# Express JS not recognizing environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables

My application folder structure is something like this.

app/
   config/
      app.js
      env.js
   server.js

Whenever I start my run my app.js file it gives me server started at undefined.
Here is the gist of the code.

[Gist Codes](https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/6692230)

```
server.js    
// Module dependencies.
var http = require('http'),
    app = require('./config/app')();

// Start server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('App is Up at '+ app.get('port') + ' as ' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
});

config/app.js
var express  =  require('express'),
    path  =  require('path'),
    ejs  =  require('ejs');

module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();
    var publicDir = path.join(__dirname, '../public');

    // Store all environment variables
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

    // Basic configuration
    app.configure(function() {
        app.use(express.logger('dev'));
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.methodOverride());
        app.use(app.router);
        app.use(express.static(publicDir));
    });

    // Environment specific configuration
    require('./env')(app);

    return app;
};
config/env.js
var express = require('express'),
    hbsPrecompiler = require('handlebars-precompiler'),
    path = require('path');

module.exports = function(app) {
    // development compile Handlebars and show errors
    app.configure('development', function(){
        app.set('db-uri', process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/App');

        hbsPrecompiler.watchDir(
            path.join(__dirname, "../public/templates"),
            path.join(__dirname, "../public/templates/compiled/templates.js"),
            ['handlebars', 'hbs']
        );
        app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });

    app.configure('production', function(){
        app.set('db-uri', process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);
    });
};
```

node server.js

## output

```
/usr/bin/node app.js
App is Up at 3000 as undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `process.env.NODE_ENV` is undefined. If you run node in the test environment, for instance (`NODE_ENV=test node app.js`) you wouldn't have that problem.

I suggest you add this line in your `module.exports` function:

```
if (app.settings.env === 'development') process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
```

Comment: It is working, one question though , if I put this in the config/app.js module.exports, is it going to get all the dev requirements that is specified in the config/env.development ?

Comment: Yes. If you add that line at the beginning of your config/env.js module.exports function, then your app will be configured as specified under your `app.configure('development'...` block.

Comment: i think it should go in the config/app.js rather than env.js cause again i have to initialize the application in the env file. Update: Nopes it should be in the env file.

Answer (score 0):

This looks different than the folder structure you mentioned:

```
app = require('./config/app')();
```

It seems reversed.

Comment: first app.js is the root file. lemme change that to server.js

Answer (score 0):

This is as expected. There is no NODE_ENV environment variable by default unless you explicitly set it, so `process.env.NODE_ENV` is undefined. There's no problem with that.